# Go to the nav tab in another blade.php after submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Basically, after pressing the submit button I want to refresh the page (so the new data from the form will be updated), and load up another view `<div class="view-practitioner">`.

I dont want to stay in the blade.php with form `<form id="practitioner_edit_form"`.

Both of those blade.php are in the same nav-link `href="#practitioner"`

I have found a way to do that using jquery with ajax, but I don't know how to finish it correctly, there are commented parts of my code that I tried, none of them did what I wanted.

js with function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#practitioner_edit_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                window.location = $('.nav-tabs a[href="#practitioner"]').tab('show');
                /*^reloads my page to http://rps.me/person/profile/49/[object%20Object] from http://rps.me/person/profile/49/Smith*/
                /*$('.nav-tabs a[href="#practitioner"]').tab('show');*/
                /*^stays in the form after submitting, changed data isn't visible, only after reload, but I want to reload to correct nav tab*/
                /*location.reload();*/
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```
@extends('person.person-dashboard')
@section('personContent')

    <div class="page-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row-no-margin">
                    <br>
                    @if ($message = Session::get('successRemove'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    @elseif($message = Session::get('failRemove'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    @elseif($message = Session::get('defaultRemoveError'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="cover-profile">
                    <div class="profile-bg-img">
                        <img class="profile-bg-img img-fluid" src="/files/assets/images/bg-img1-30opacity.png"
                             alt="bg-img">
                        <div class="card-block user-info">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <div class="card-block">
                                        <div class="img-hover">
                                            {{--Check if the picture is null, if so show default image--}}
                                            @if (is_null($person->avatar))
                                                <img class="img-fluid img-radius"
                                                     src="{{asset('storage/images/userImage/standard/default.png')}}"
                                                     width="150"
                                                     height="150" alt="user-img">
                                                <div class="img-overlay img-radius">
                                            <span>
                                                <a href="/person/profile/{{$person->person_id}}/{{$person->last_name}}/uploadfile"
                                                   class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                                    <i class="icofont icofont-edit"></i></a>
                                            </span>
                                                    @else
                                                        <img class="img-fluid img-radius"
                                                             src="{{asset('storage/images/userImage/standard').'/'.$person->avatar}}"
                                                             width="150"
                                                             height="150" alt="user-img">
                                                        <div class="img-overlay img-radius">
                                            <span>
                                                <a href="/person/profile/{{$person->person_id}}/{{$person->last_name}}/uploadfile"
                                                   class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                                    <i class="icofont icofont-edit"></i></a>
                                                <a href="/person/profile/{{$person->person_id}}/{{$person->last_name}}/remove"
                                                   class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-sm btn-danger waves-effect waves-light active"
                                                   name="delete-image" id="delete-image-button"
                                                   onclick="return confirm(trans('collaborators.areYouSure'))">
                                                    <i class="icofont icofont-ui-delete"></i></a>
                                            </span>
                                                            @endif
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="user-title">
                                                @if ($person->person_title == null)
                                                    <h2>{{$person->first_name}} {{$person->last_name}}</h2>
                                                @else
                                                    <h2>{{$person->person_title->name}} {{$person->first_name}} {{$person->last_name}}</h2>
                                                @endif
                                                <span>{{$person->mobile}}, {{$person->email}}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="cover-profile">
                        <div class="profile-bg-img">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-block user-info">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="media-body row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="user-title">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="pull-right cover-btn">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="tab-header card">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-tabs tab-timeline" role="tablist" id="mytab">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#personal" role="tab"
                               aria-expanded="true">{{trans('navigation.general')}}</a>

                            <div class="slide"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#practitioner" role="tab"
                               aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.practitioner')}}</a>

                            <div class="slide"></div>
                        </li>
                        @isset($practitioner->practitioner_id)
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#availability" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.availability')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#absence" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.absence')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#contract" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.contract')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#training" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.training')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#history" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.history')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#access" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.access')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                        @endisset
                        @empty($practitioner->practitioner_id)
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#availability" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.availability')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#absence" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.absence')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#contract" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.contract')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#training" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.training')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#history" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.history')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#access" role="tab"
                                   aria-expanded="false">{{trans('navigation.access')}}</a>

                                <div class="slide"></div>
                            </li>
                        @endempty
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="personal" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <button id="edit-btn" type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-editpanel btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light f-right">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-edit"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-block">
                                @include('person.profile.info-display')
                                @include('person.profile.info-edit')
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="practitioner" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true">
                        <div class="card">
                            @isset($practitioner->practitioner_id)
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <button id="edit-practitioner-btn" type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-editpanel btn-sm btn-primary waves-effect waves-light f-right">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-edit"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            @endisset
                            <div class="card-block">
                                @include('person.profile.practitioner.practitioner-display')
                                @isset($practitioner->practitioner_id)
                                    @include('person.profile.practitioner.practitioner-edit')
                                @endisset
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="availability" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                        <div class="row">
                            {{trans('navigation.availability')}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="contract" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                        <div class="row">
                            {{trans('navigation.contract')}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="training" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                        <div class="row">
                            @include('person.profile.training.training')
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="absence" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                        <div class="row">
                            {{trans('navigation.absence')}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="history" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                        <div class="row">
                            {{trans('navigation.history')}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="access" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
                        <div class="row">
                            {{trans('navigation.access')}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- tab content end -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @include("settings.remove-confirmation")

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/assets/css/custom-person-profile.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/assets/css/custom-j-forms.css">
        <script src="/files/js/views/person/person-profile.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/services/initialization.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/services/editButton.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/services/practitioner/editPractitionerButton.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/services/colors.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/modules/dataTable.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/modules/update.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/modules/create.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/modules/displayInfo.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/services/forms.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/services/validation.js"></script>
        <script src="/files/js/settings/setup-ajax-requests.js"></script>
@endsection
```

I commented on what codes that I tried did after submitting the form.

Comment: Why have you chosen for both the `#view-practioner` and form to be in the same blade file? Can this be changed to solve your issue?

Comment: They are not in the same blade file, they are just in the same tab-pane of the nav-tab with `href="#practitioner"`


```php
<div class="card-block">
                                @include('person.profile.practitioner.practitioner-display')
                                @isset($practitioner->practitioner_id)
                                    @include('person.profile.practitioner.practitioner-edit')
                                @endisset
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you paste your nav data

Comment: @thisiskelvin added the whole code that I use for navigation of those tabs